# Meta Tags on Brands Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, meta-tags

I recently purchased  and installed a Shop By Brands extension from Mageplaza. Once installed I realized the actual Brands Page did not have a Meta Tags (Title, Keywords, Description) section. Is it possible to create a file for that page that can have this feature. The actual individual brands do have the tags. Need the main Shop By Brands page to display the tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Option.1**
Add in phtml.(if dynamic value) for that open your brands xml file like. brand_index_index.xml and add below code

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional"> <block 
class="Vendor\Module\Block\CustomHead" name="custom_head" 
template="Vendor_Module::custom_head.phtml"/> </referenceBlock>
```

now create "custom_head.phtml" in your "view/frontend/templates" and add your code as your need. lie below

```
<meta name="title" content="Welcome Brands"/>
<meta name="description" content="This is brands test descriptions"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Brands, brand, your keywords"/>
```

**option 2.** you can directly add meta tag in xml instead of php

open your module xml file . like "brand_index_index.xml" and add below code. dont replace existing code please set as per your need.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
    <meta name="title" content="Welcome Brands"/>
    <meta name="description" content="This is brands test descriptions"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Brands, brand, your keywords"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

accept solution if helps you